# How to get real time data from android Recognizer Intent?

Tags: android, kotlin, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

1. I would like to call the `RecognizerIntent` and have it loop forever until the user decides to close it, how would I go about doing this?  the current android recognizer intent closes whenever the sound stops after a recognized input. For example: if "hi" was recognized, if the user doesn't say anything after that for about one or two seconds the Activity closes. Any way I can stop the activity from closing? and going forever until I choose to close it(perhaps by a click of the button a second time?)'
2. I would also like to get real-time data back as to what is being said, instead of having it passed as extra data from the activity after it closes.

   ```
   package com.example.myapplication

   import android.app.Activity
   import android.content.Intent
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
   import android.os.Bundle
   import android.speech.RecognizerIntent
   import android.widget.Toast
   import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_recordinit.*
   import java.lang.Exception
   import java.util.*

   class Recordinit : AppCompatActivity() {

    val   REQUESTCODE3 = 4



   fun audioaction(){
       val speechtotextintent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
       speechtotextintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL)
       speechtotextintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE , Locale.getDefault())
       speechtotextintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT , "Click To Begin Listening on the threat!!")
       try {
           //check to see if the activity can work on this device... and it meets the requirements
           startActivityForResult(speechtotextintent , REQUESTCODE3 )


       }
       //if there is any errors we will let the user know in a popup message.
       catch (e : Exception){
           Toast.makeText(this , e.message , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT  ).show()

       }



   }

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_recordinit)
       microphonebutton.setOnClickListener{
           audioaction()

       }


   }

   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        if (REQUESTCODE3 == requestCode ){
           when (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ){



           }

       }
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
   }
   ```

   }

EDIT: I found out that the `EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS` would allow me do dictate how the activity reacts to silence. But I still would like to find a way to monitor what is being said in real-time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you to get the words said when activity called.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE10) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            var result : ArrayList<String> = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)
        }
    }
}
```